# Sharpie binding error : Unsupported clang availability platform: 'macCatalyst'

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, objective-sharpie, xamarin.ios-binding

I'm trying to bind a framework into my Xamarin iOS project using this command:

```
sharpie bind -output FrameworkName -namespace FrameworkName -sdk iphoneos13.2 -scope Headers FrameworkName.framework/Headers/HeaderFile.h -c IHeaders -arch arm64
```

I got this error:

```
System.Exception: Unsupported clang availability platform: 'macCatalyst'
```

I have the latest Mac OS `Catalina`, the latest XcCode version `11.3.1`, and the `3.4.0` Sharpie version.

Is there a way to solve this without downgrading the OS?

Comment: Can you give us more information about the VS that you have?

Answer (score 0):

About **[Mac Catalyst](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/mac_catalyst?language=objc)** , you can have a check whehther library project select this **option** : *Mac (requires macOS 10.15)*

[image]

If so unselect it , and rebuild project to use sharpie binding .